# Listview scroll till end like pagination

Tags: android, json, android-listview

After lot of search and trial in SO and Google here i am back again without getting endless scroll in listview :(... when i scroll to end of listview it should load more items in listview like pagination. Following is my code can any one help to solve this issue? Answers will be really appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener{
//implement onScrollListener for scrolling {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
JSONArray posts;


/*
* some private variables to implement endless scrolling
*/
private int visibleThreshold = 3;
private int previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = true;



// All static variables
static final String URL = "siteurl";


 static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
 static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";



public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

if(loading){
//if trying to loading
if(totalItemCount > previousTotal){

loading = false;
previousTotal = totalItemCount;
}
}

if(!loading && ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))){
new LoadMoreEntries().execute();
loading = true;
}
}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Dialog loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading.Please wait...",false);

return loadingDialog;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }




            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }



         final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);    
             list.setAdapter(adapter);



    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String content = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content)).getText().toString();



            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SampleDesp.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DATE, date);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_CONTENT, content);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });


}
class LoadMoreEntries extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                        // show your dialog
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        showDialog(1);
                        }

                        protected String doInBackground(ArrayList... params) {
                        // do your request here

                         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


                            // Creating JSON Parser instance
                                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                                    // getting JSON string from URL
                                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                                    try {
                                         posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

                            // looping through all song nodes <song>
                                    for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                                        JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                                        // Storing each json item in variable
                                        String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                                        String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                                        String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                                        String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                                        // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                                         content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                                         content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                                         content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                                        //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                                        JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                                        String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                                        String url = null;
                                        String slug = null;
                                        try {
                                        JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                                        for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                                            JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                                            slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                                            JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                                            JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                                            url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                                        }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();

                                        }




                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put(KEY_ID, id);
                                map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                                map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
                                map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
                                map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
                                map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
                                map.put(KEY_URL, url);


                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                songsList.add(map);
                                    }   
                                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                        }



                        return null;
                        }

                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        // close the dialog and notify adapter for data
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        Dialog loadingDialog = null;
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //dismiss the progress dialog
                        }



                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }
                        }
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
   }
```

Comment: what does your code do now? what problems r u facing?

Comment: My code is displaying first 10 items in listview its not loading more items @AndroSelva

Comment: shouldn't you call notifyDatasetChanged *after* loadElements ? (also, you'll notice you are doing network on the ui thread). Also, in loadElements, you are using a new songList, which you don't use afterward. Use a single fields for this (and try to use loadElements only, don't duplicate the code in the onCreate)

Comment: now i followed this tutorial http://burakdede.com/2012/07/06/endless-scroll-effect-with-android/ and edited my code but out is same can you plz look into it @AndroSelva

Comment: @AndroSelva have u done endless listview scroll?

Comment: no my friend. I have not done it so far. But couldn't find the problem with your code too. Sorry!!